# vim delete a char or an CR after the cursor

Tags: vim

i got some situation like this (in normal mode)

```
    ...
    \}
]
```

i want to make it

```
    ...
    \}]
```

my way is use <kbd>i</kbd> to insert before the ] and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete the CR.

is there a more efficient way to make this change?(like cursor on the } and delete CR after it?)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this way:

go to the second line

press `gJ`

Comment: wow!this is exactly what i want,the <kbd>g</kbd> is really powerful,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the extra space, it's very simple. While you are on the line with `\}`, you just press `J`. It doesn't matter where you are on the line, it will join the next line with it and delimit with a space and place the cursor at the space. If you don't want the space, press `x` then you're done.

So just `J` if you want the space, or `Jx` without space and you can start anywhere on the `\}` line.

Comment: I don't think Jx works.  I think it deletes the wrong char.  You are right about anywhere on the line, though.

Comment: @Jim, in `vim` version 7.3 it does the correct character (I tried it on several different cases, including the OP's example). What version of `vim` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Goto the second line with \} on it.
Hit Cap J
Hit escape and x out any spaces as needed.

Comment: Capital J  J-ions the two lines together.

Answer (score 1):

And another way, because that's Vim we are talking about:

```
:j!
```